# Problems with JSON getting data from tmi.twitch.tv api

Tags: json, hosts

Problem is when i try to use this code to get the log from tmi.twitch.tv api using url: http://tmi.twitch.tv/hosts?include_logins=1&target=70219146 i get Systax Error Unexpected Token. The code is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         $.getJSON("http://tmi.twitch.tv/hosts?include_logins=1&target=70219146&callback=?", function (data) {
          console.log(data.hosts)  
});
    })
```

I can get the data using php and json array like this:

```
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://tmi.twitch.tv/hosts?include_logins=1&target=70219146'), true);
echo $json_array['hosts']['0']['host_login']."</br>";
```

But isnt there a way to use do this in html? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to request regular JSON as JSONp (`&callback=?` activates jQuery's JSONp request method) which actually embeds the response into a `<script>` to execute it. However, the twitch API still returns JSON which is not valid JavaScript. Unless there is a way to make tmi.twitch.tv return valid JSONp, there is no way to do this directly from JavaScript unless you use a proxy like http://crossorigin.me/.