# Cross-origin JSON request

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain

I am writing HTML/CSS/JS for a Twitch.tv application. I request (public, non-sensitive) data through their main [API endpoint](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API) (api.twitch.tv), but one piece of data has not been integrated. This data, however, is viewable at another sub-domain (tmi.twitch.tv). Unfortunately, when I make a $.getJSON call (or $.AJAX with dataType: JSON), I receive the following in Firefox 44.0.2:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://tmi.twitch.tv/{rest of URL}. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

I've known of this security mechanism as a user, but not as a (*novice*) programmer. I read a lot in attempt to manage, but I am still lost.

**What I've gathered**:
A common workaround is requesting JSONP. Unlike JSON, the browser does not enforce cross-origin policy on JSONP. I know that the main Twitch API is JSONP-friendly and probably has CORS enabled. In contrast, I imagine tmi.twitch.tv does not have CORS enabled.

**What I've tried:**
I've appended my request URL with `?callback=`, `?callback=differentStrings`, and `?otherQuery=value&callback=differentStrings`. These did not work. I changed my dataType to jsonp, and without additional query strings (just changing dataType appended two query strings: callback=jQuery{long number}_{long number} & _={long number}, I did not receive an x-origin block. However, I did get the following:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement | Line 1: Character 8

for this object I requested:

```
{"hosts":[{"host_id":118084843,"target_id":41981587,"host_login":"politecpu","target_login":"politemaster"},{"host_id":118082906,"target_id":41981587,"host_login":"politerobot","target_login":"politemaster"}]}
```

I am stuck. I do not know if this is a problem with the format of the data/JSONP nor if I found a workaround for x-origin, as my success(-ful receipt of data) function did not work. What should I consider next?

I'd like to emphasize that I am an *absolute novice* (I only recently completed Codecademy lessons for JS and jQuery). Thank you kindly in advance for thoughts and comments.

(Edit) My function:

```js
var allHosts = [];  // To be compared against new JSON periodically called via checkHosts()
var getHosts = function() {
 allHosts = [];
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://tmi.twitch.tv/hosts?include_logins=1&target=' + myID,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
   data.hosts.forEach(function(element) {
    allHosts.push(element.host_id);
   });
   debug('getHosts():', 'data =', data, 'allHosts =', allHosts, 'queue =', queue, 'busy =', busy); // Not relevant
  },
 });
}
```

Comment: It looks like valid JSON. How are you using the object in your code? I think that's where your problem is.

Comment: Sorry for the delay (I had trouble formatting the code). I just amended my question with it. @caszi

Comment: What line is the error on relative to the snippet? Could it be the comma at the end of the success object?

Comment: The error actually refers to the data requested, according to my Firefox console (I was surprised). I click on the link the Firefox console provides and it opens the page source for the data.

Comment: I should have also said that I did try removing the last comma after the 'success' value, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165925/jsonp-call-showing-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016785/problems-with-json-getting-data-from-tmi-twitch-tv-api) it looks like you are trying to access a JSON resource using JSONP. The domain does not support JSONP.

You might be able to accomplish what you want using a server side language which will fetch the resource on behalf of the user.

Comment: I really appreciate your responses, caszi. I am still reading through all the links that cascaded from the two you provided me with. From the second, in which the programmer was interested in the same sub-domain as me, I found that he/she and others are using other programming languages. I am currently wondering if I should learn some PHP or C# to request this JSON. I am also learning more about cross-origin. I will be back to post again.

Comment: I learned a bit of PHP, although I needed an interpreter to use it in local files. I opted for using XAMPP (although I am not sure this is the best/lightest way to run PHP).  I made a separate .php file with `<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo file_get_contents('http://tmi.twitch.tv/hosts?include_logins=1&target=' . $myID);
?>` to capture the data. I then use the same JavaScript AJAX call (`url: localFile.php`) to manipulate it. Thank you again for setting me on the right path, @caszi! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding a header to your request

```
    var allHosts = [];
    // To be compared against new JSON periodically called via checkHosts()
    var getHosts = function() {
    allHosts = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://tmi.twitch.tv/hosts?include_logins=1&target=' + myID,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        headers: {

                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':URLofOrigin

                       },
        success: function(data) {
            data.hosts.forEach(function(element) {
                allHosts.push(element.host_id);
            });
            debug('getHosts():', 'data =', data, 'allHosts =', allHosts, 'queue =', queue, 'busy =', busy); // Not relevant
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: I was looking for the syntax to include headers! Thanks, Bhawana. Unfortunately, this did not change anything. When requesting with `dataType: 'jsonp'`, I still get the aforementioned syntax error. With `dataType: 'json'`, I still get the cross-origin policy message. That further makes me believe tmi.twitch.tv does not support CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - https://api.allowallorigin.com/restapi?url=https://tmi.twitch.tv/hosts?include_logins=1&target=007

I have created this solution after trying multiple options. The other solution on the same line does the job but changes the JSON Data locations until one pays for it. Above service is free and will continue to remain free. If people find it useful, then I may put a home page and few google ads but otherwise it should continue to remain free for foreseeable future.

Here is an example code:

```
jPath.prototype.loadJSONDataFromUrl = function(_url, callback) {
    $.getJSON(_url, function(data) {
        $.fn.jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    }).done(function(json){
        if( callback != null) {
            callback();
        }
    }).fail(function(){
        $.getJSON('https://api.allowallorigin.com/allorigin/restapi?url='+_url, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            $.fn.jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
        }).done(function(json){
            if( callback != null) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    });
}
```